# f(write) php doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, fwrite

```
$abc = @fopen("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/../public_html/zamowienia.txt",'ab');
if(!$abc)
{
     echo "<br /><br />Zamowienie Panstwa nie moze zostac przyjete w tej chwili. Prosze sprobowac pozniej.";
}
$ciagwyjsciowy = $CPU."\t".$Cenazamowienia_netto."\t".$Cenazamowienia_brutto."\n";
fwrite($abc, $ciagwyjsciowy);
fclose($abc);
```

this warning will display

```
Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/a6907098/public_html/Sklep/process.php on line 27
```

What's wrong with the code?

PHP Error Message

```
Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/a6907098/public_html/Sklep/process.php on line 28
```

Answer (score 0):

using @ in fopen will make file handler to return 0 errors, which means if your file wasnt opened, there will be no error returned. replace @fopen with fopen.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$abc = fopen("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/../public_html/zamowienia.txt",'a');
if(!$abc)
{
     echo "<br /><br />Zamowienie Panstwa nie moze zostac przyjete w tej chwili. Prosze sprobowac pozniej.";
}
else
{
  $ciagwyjsciowy = $CPU."\t".$Cenazamowienia_netto."\t".$Cenazamowienia_brutto."\n";
   fwrite($abc, $ciagwyjsciowy);
   fclose($abc);
}
```

and see what happened. i hope you will find solution

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because your $abc variable it's "**is not a valid stream resource**"
Maybe something wrong with your path to file.

Try this please:

```
$abc = fopen("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/../public_html/zamowienia.txt",'ab');
if(!$abc)
{
     die("<br /><br />Zamowienie Panstwa nie moze zostac przyjete w tej chwili. Prosze sprobowac pozniej.");

}else{
    $ciagwyjsciowy = $CPU."\t".$Cenazamowienia_netto."\t".$Cenazamowienia_brutto."\n";
    fwrite($abc, $ciagwyjsciowy);
    fclose($abc);
}
```

I'm sorry but code looks awful :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead of `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` ?

Also if you get printed `Zamowienie Panstwa nie moze zostac przyjete w tej chwili. Prosze sprobowac pozniej.` it means that you got no file pointer so you can try Satish Sharma answer.

Comment: I have on the top $DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; so I guess it's correct.

Comment: Yup, it's correct. Have you tried `file_put_contents()` instead of `fopen()` `fwrite()` and `fclose()` ?